# Saving stream(mp4) on iphone

Tags: iphone, video, download, stream, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I need your help guys.
Im working on an app where the user can either watch a stream(mp4) or download it.
I've succeded to download the stream (mp4) on the iphone simulator and the file is there and it works perfect, but when I try to run the app on the iphone it will not work. The file is there but I can't play it. Please help... (It's done in Monotouch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to file encoding iPhone 3G and other iOS device can play only a specific subset of mp4 file.

In Apple documentation of [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html):

> This class plays any movie or audio
>   file supported in iOS. This includes
>   both streamed content and fixed-length
>   files. For movie files, this typically
>   means files with the extensions .mov,
>   .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of
>   the following compression standards:
>
> - H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The
>     Baseline profile does not support B
>     frames.)
> - MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)
>
> If you use this class to play audio
>   files, it displays a white screen with
>   a QuickTime logo while the audio
>   plays. For audio files, this class
>   supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz,
>   and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to
>   48 kHz, stereo audio.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It works perfect when I run the app/code in my simulator, I can play the video. But it does not work on the iphone.

Comment: I repeat che that the mp4 file as encoded as said. You can also try to rencode the file with Handbrake (on osx) using the iPhone/iPod preset. Just as a test